# Cosmos DB .NET 3.0 SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I saw that with new .NET SDK we can return stream from a query, so I try to do that, to avoid serialization/deserialization and to save some time.

But the issue was if my query should return more than 8k records I will lose records because all the time max count of elements is around 7800. Is there a way to increase this, because I couldn't find that there is a maximum number of elements that query can return in one iteration?
I do not want to iterate through response, also I am not using continuation token, I just want to drop response as a stream.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that GetItemStreamIterator  is the method you must be using to query for stream.This gets an iterator to go through all the items for the container as the original CosmosResponseMessage

This is the set of parameter you can to query it.

Parameters

maxItemCount -Nullable
(Optional) The max item count to return as part of the query

continuationToken- String
(Optional) The continuation token in the Azure Cosmos DB service.

requestOptions- CosmosItemRequestOptions
(Optional) The options for the item query request CosmosQueryRequestOptions

```js
public class ToDoActivity{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string status {get; set;}
}

CosmosResultSetIterator setIterator = this.Container.Items.GetItemStreamIterator();
while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    using (CosmosResponseMessage iterator = await setIterator.FetchNextSetAsync())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(iterator.Content))
        {
            string content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Have you tried passing maxcount(more than 8k) in the query. See if it helps.

**Note:** It is always good to have continuationtoken in the query to have more control.

Comment: Hi, @Mohil Thanks for your answer. 
Yes, I tried to set MaxItemCount to be more than 8k but still, it's stuck on some 7k value.
I am creating an azure function to be a wrapper around cosmos db, and i am not really happy with response time ( 8MB response its returned in 4-5s) so i am trying some other approaches to decrease time. 
Thanks again.